# Postgres. How to convert string that contains '\' to bytea?

Tags: postgresql, text, backslash, bytea

I have string `'test\data'` or just one backslash symbol `'\'`.

How it convert to bytea?

Comment: Use the `convert_to` function: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-binarystring.html

Comment: Thanks!)
`select convert_to('test\data'::text, 'utf8')`

Answer (score 4):

Backlashes need special handling if casted from to `bytea` see [`src/backend/utils/adt/varlena.c`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/def5b065ff22a16a80084587613599fe15627213/src/backend/utils/adt/varlena.c#L305).

Thus escape each backslash using `replace('test\data', '\', '\\')::bytea` before casting to `bytea`.

You could also use the already suggested function `convert_to(text, encoding) bytea`. But note that this function is **not** [`IMMUTABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-volatility.html) and thus it can't be used in any context out of the box.